# Automatically move a script into the background

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is it possible for a running script to move itself into the background?

I have a goal:
I run the script: `./script.sh`.
The script asks me for a password:

```
echo -n PASSWORD:
read -s pass
if [ "${scriptPassword}" == "$pass" ] && [[ ${pass_counter} = 0 ]]; then
pass_counter = $ ((pass_counter + 1))
echo "PASSWORD OK"
```

And then I want to achieve the same effect
as when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
and then run the command `bg`. 
Can I run such commands inside a script?

I want the script to start working as if it had been started with
`nohup ./script.sh &`,
but only after the user enters the correct password.

Comment: You probably mean `bg %1`. `bg $1` does work, too, but for unexpected reasons... The reference to the newest job is `%%` so that should be used.

Comment: Possibly just add ‘bg’ as a new line after your last echo. Bg by itself should background the current job, however I can’t verify that now.

Comment: Do you want the `bg`  to happen inside a script? What is your script doing? Please **edit your question** to improve it. I have not understood it as some other people. So please make your question more clear.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch connects to a database and runs heavy sql scripts

Comment: Don't comment your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it. **Your question is unclear and needs a *lot* of improvements.**

Comment: @HaukeLaging  understands the task.
BasileStarynkevitchIf you do not know the answer then do not spam.

Comment: @Dani_l You should try something like that before you recommend it.

Comment: There are several typos in your `if` line. `[` and `]` need spaces around them. There must not be a space after `$`. Arithmetic comparisons are done with `-eq` not with `=`. Using `[` and `[[` together without the special features of `[[` seems a bit strange.

Comment: Smells awfully bad as some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). If the real issue is about database connection, that should be mentioned in the question (not only in comment), and the actual RDBMS should be mentioned, and the relevant commands also! As too often, complete lack of motivation in the question (not in comments) make them unclear.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What database problem?
what are you talking about ?

Comment: 38 minutes ago, MartinusP wrote: "connects to a database and runs heavy sql scripts" as a comment (the 4th in chronological order above)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 
This is the answer to your question: "What is your script doing"

Comment: And I am wishing you would put that in  your question itself, and give more details (e.g. what RDBMS)! Consider that we should not read your comments to understand your question (because comments could disappear, be ordered differently, etc).

Comment: But your problem is unclear and is an XY problem. And scripts or jobs (or processes) don't "move", so that verb is inappropriate (and makes your question confusing).

Comment: Translations for [move in Polish](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-polish/move) are available on line. I'm sure you want some other verb.

Answer (score 7):

#### 1. A Direct Approach

This is somewhat similar to [Hauke Laging’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403895/80216#403901) but simpler. 
After your script has finished its interactive business, do

```
(kill -STOP $$; kill -CONT $$) &
sleep 1
```

Here, the script spawns a very small (asynchronous) subshell
to STOP it (the script process),
very much the same<sup>*</sup> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does,
and then restart it with a **cont**intue signal,
very much the same as `bg` does. 
You might not even need the `sleep`;
I just thought that it might be safer
if the script wasn’t doing anything important when the signal came in.

I have tested this, but only superficially,
so there may be surprises if you use it in a real application context.
____________
<sup>*</sup> Different in that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends SIGTSTP. 
You could probably use SIGTSTP in the script instead of  SIGSTOP. 
I tested it with SIGSTOP, and, if that works,
I don’t see any reason to change it.

#### 2. Arguably Simpler (and maybe more portable?)

Have the script invoke itself asynchronously.

```
if [ "$exported_pass" != "$scriptPassword" ]
then
    [ Insert here appropriate code to read pass from the user and loop     ]
    [ until it is correct (or there have been too many tries, so we exit). ]
    # So at this point, "$scriptPassword" == "$pass"
    exported_pass="$pass"
    export exported_pass
    nohup "$0" "$@" &
    exit
fi
```

The first time the script runs, `$exported_pass` will not be set,
so it goes into the `if`-`then` and asks for the password. 
Then it puts it into the `exported_pass` environment variable
and invokes itself asynchronously —
and then the main (parent) process exits. 
The second invocation of the script, which is running in the background,
sees the password in the environment, and just goes ahead and does its job.

Comment: Yeah... Your approach (2) is what I tried first but I forgot the `exit` and thus was under the wrong impression that this doesn't work. Unfortunately you managed to put three errors in a single line... `pass_counter = $ ((pass_counter + 1))`

Comment: Well, I didn’t ***put*** them there; I copied them verbatim from the question. And, yes, it would have been better if I had fixed them (as I fixed the `if` itself), but I didn’t notice that I had overlooked those errors until six minutes after I posted the answer, and I didn’t want to do an edit for something so minor.   :-)   ⁠

Comment: Isn't the second solution an endless loop. When I miss type the password the subscript gets started anyway and it then starts itself again or am I missing something. Just read the code haven't tried it.

Comment: But `[ "$exported_pass" != "$scriptPassword" ]` is true when the second if condition is false, so it does it again, right?

Comment: if_1 :`[ "" != "abc" ]` -> `read pass` = abx  -> if_2: `[ "abc" == "abx" ] -> `nohup "$0" "$@" &` -> export export_pass="abx"-> if_1 in sub process : `[ "abx" != "abc" ]` This is a little bit compressed. but shoud make it clear.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens: Check it again.  It’s incomplete, but I believe it explains better what’s supposed to be there. Thanks for calling it to my attention.

Comment: Brief test of `(kill -STOP $$; kill -CONT $$)` without `&` seems to work--any reason you need to run the subshell in parallel?  Seems to be the entire logic behind having the sleep in there.

Comment: @Angelo: Interesting observation.  My testing confirms your result, and I can't think of any reason why the ```&``` would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a trap in the parent shell before running the script so that the script can trigger the call of `bg`. The problem is that the trap is not executed while the script is running.

As the terminal just sends `SIGSTOP` to the script (after which the parent shell gains control again), the trick is for the script to do this itself:

```
# preparation in the parent shell
trap 'bg %%' USR1
```

The script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# parent shell has executed: trap 'bg %%' USR1

# pass or determine this value
PARENT_SHELL_PID=5646

read -p "enter value: " input
kill -USR1 $PARENT_SHELL_PID # execution of this in parent shell is delayed
kill -STOP $$ # returns control to parent shell

sleep 1000
```

**sourcing a wrapper script**

If it is acceptable to have two scripts and to source one of them (i.e. run it in the current shell context instead of as a subshell) then it becomes even easier:

The wrapper script:

```
PARENT_SHELL_PID=$$ ./script.sh
bg %%
```

The actual script:

```
#! /bin/bash

test -z "$PARENT_SHELL_PID" && exit 2

read -p "enter value: " input

# return control to sourced wrapper script
kill -STOP $$

# continue in the background
sleep 1000
```

Both are run with

```
. wrapper.sh
```

Comment: I would not like a parent shell.
echo -n PASSWORD:
read -s pass
if ["$ {scriptPassword}" == "$ pass"] && [[$ {pass_counter} = 0]]; then
pass_counter = $ ((pass_counter + 1))
echo "PASSWORD OK" 
It would be easier to run the second script already in the background
nohup script2.sh &

Comment: @MartinusP: Please **edit your question** instead of adding comments.

Comment: @MartinusP I do not understand your comment. You do not like the solution you asked for (any more)? Certainly there are different possible approaches.

Comment: I believe it’s possible to do better, and I have posted an answer.

Answer (score -2):

> Is it possible to *move* a running script to a background shell?

<sup>The use of "move" is confusing. You mean some other verb, very probably (I can't guess which one). I'm taking it literally....</sup>

A [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) is just a [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) (not the same as a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) interpreting that script, and you could have *several* processes - or none - running that script). You could move it (with [`mv(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) or using [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) in some program) while it is running. But the shell interpreting it would have already some opened [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) on it, so that won't change anything. Actually, **you don't want to move a script** (and you don't move processes or jobs; however you can move files). The "move" verb is very confusing (at least to me, I am not a native English speaker) and I don't understand what and why you really want to do.

<sup>(a different question is what happens when you *overwrite* a script during its execution, but you don't ask that)</sup>

It looks like you want some program mimicking the action of a user inside a (pseudo-) terminal. Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page (terminals and pseudo-ttys are very complex, I forgot the details). Use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to mimic a user inside a terminal.

BTW, managing passwords in scripts is risky ([security holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)) are easy to make) and error prone, so smells really bad. I would try hard to avoid that, e.g. by using `ssh` with public & private keys.

So better redesign your entire thing to avoid supplying passwords automatically (inside scripts).

You apparently want to do (but it is unclear to me if you want to do that yourself in your terminal, or from inside another script):

<kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd>

```
 bg %%
```

This is about [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)). The fact that what goes in the background is a process running some shell interpreting a script or some other plain executable program is irrelevant. [Unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) are ordinary programs from the kernel's point of view. IIRC, job control is related to [process groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group).

In a comment, you mention connecting to some database. Most [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) client programs provide some way to give the password in a more appropriate manner (perhaps [`--login-path` for `mysql` command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_login-path)). If you want to do that from another script some [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) could be handy (that *here document* could contain or synthesize some SQL commands). Notice also that RDBMS systems won't alter their databases when authentication failed.

> Can I run such commands inside a script?

I don't understand what commands (is it `bg %%`) you want to run inside a script. If you want to drive job control from a script (but I believe you should not) then `expect` is probably more suitable.

> I want the script to start working like `nohup ./scripts.sh &` but only after entering the correct password

That edit *confuses me* even more. What password are you talking about (I am not sure if your script provides a password to some RDBMS server, or requires one to be run completely)? **I am guessing** that you have some long-running script doing something related to databases (e.g. a backup lasting several hours). If that is indeed the case, you need to ask a different question. You could for example store the (interactively input) password somewhere and later run the backup in batch (perhaps using the [`batch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/batch) command with some *here document*). BTW, various RDBMS have different ways to provide the password and do the authentication so you really need to mention, in your future question, what actual RDBMS you are using.

<sup>So consider improving your question to motivate it a lot and give more context. I'm only guessing, and I could guess very wrong!</sup>

Or maybe you want the equivalent of [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) in your shell? That would make yet another question (and since bash is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you can always patch it to add a new [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) inside it). I think (but I am not sure at all) that [`exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) shell builtin might be useful.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: Perhaps, then I am waiting for your better answer.

Comment: Move a running script clearly refers to the process, not the file containing the script

Comment: AFAIK, you don't move processes neither. The OP is using the wrong words.

Comment: I don’t think you need %%, ad you are still the current job

Comment: The OP talks about `CTRL+Z` and you write "You apparently want to do CTRL+Z"? You obviously haven't even read the short question. Incredible for a 5k rep user.

Comment: As I read the first few lines of this answer, I began composing (in my mind) the slightly snarky comment that I would address to the neophyte who wrote it.   I was astonished when I saw your name — I expect better things of you.